How to handle associated column values in LibreOffice calc?
I have a column that is validated with a list from another sheet. I want the column to the right of that column to populate with a value associated with the value from the first column. That is, when I select a value in column A from the pull-down menu, I want the formula in column B to reference another string associated with the first value (a category).
It is easy enough to construct the two lists in two columns, but how do I refer to the second column of the list by the value from the first column?
I realize that this is trying to get a spreadsheet to behave like a database. Is that maybe asking too much?

VLOOKUP? INDEX/MATCH?

Thanks!  VLOOKUP did the trick.
